# Developer specific application settings in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

What is the best way of storing/loading developer specific application configuration settings in asp.net core. The support it provides for Dev/Staging/Production is great but...

Answer (score 1):

It looks that you need [user secrets](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/app-secrets.html).

Sensitive values are stored in 'separate' place on machine, and app during startup add this values to other settings.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I suppose I could use a user secret to specifiy a developer appsettings override. Then if we are running in development environment reload the configuration settings with the developer specific app settings.!

Comment: Just discovered the Secrets dll and tool only support projects built against .net core and not those that use the .netframework... 
The above logic using an environment variable works better